# CSS - Problems with z-index and overlapping divs

Tags: css

I have some problems with my main menu bar. The menu bar has three levels; level one holds the main items, level 2 is the menu that goes down as soon as I put the mouse over a level 1 item and the level 3 menu appears on the right side of the level 2 menu. You can see these things on the following image:

[image]

What I want to achieve is that the level three menu is covered by the level two menu, exactly like it is shown on the picture. I want the shadow to be on the level three menu.

Now at the moment it is the other way round, namely the level three menu lies on the level two menu. So the shadow of the level 3 menu is placed on the level 2 menu. You can see this by clicking on the following link: http://beleveneleven.bplaced.net/

I tried this by changing the z-index, creating a new stack layer by using the :before pseudo-css selector, but nothing worked until now.

Any help is very appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: `creating a new stack layer by using the :before pseudo-css selector` doesn't create new stack layer really.

Comment: Ok, but how should I do it? Have you any proposition?

Comment: You would need to make it so the level 3 menu is not a child of the level 2 menu. If the elements make a hierarchy every child will inherit the parent's z-index. More info here: [Understanding CSS z-index.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index)

Comment: Ok, and there is no way to create a new stack layer somehow?

Comment: There are lots of ways. Changing the positioning to `absolute` when the parent doesn't have `position:relative`, changing the opacity to .99, etc.

Comment: Zach, could you explain that more detailled please? What do you mean by changing the opacity to 99%?

Comment: In the end, it won't matter (for the effect you want) if the new stacking context is a child of the old stacking context. Each stacking context is self-contained: after the element's contents are stacked, the whole element is considered in the stacking order of the parent stacking context. Read the link I posted, it is very useful information for understanding what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the cool article Marcelo. So do you have any idea how I could solve this issue withou changing the hierarchy? I would be very thankful.

Comment: Ha now it works, I had to remove the z-index of the parent menu and also the opacity-attribute. As it is said in Marcelo's article, the opacity attribute prevents the layering. Thanks especially Marcelo for your help!